# Django - Custom save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I have a model form, with a custom `save()` method. When I pass the variable `instance` into the form, I get the following error:

```
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

How do I handle the `instance` argument in my save method? I know with `commit` it's just a simple boolean handle, but it seems more complicated when passing an object. Thanks a bunch!

```
class UpdateOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #Some Data Here

    class Meta:
        model = Order


    def save(self, instance):
        updatedOrder= super(UpdatedOrderForm, self).save()
        #Some stuff happens here 
        return updatedOrder
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback and the place you are calling `save()`. Note, though, `instance` is usually a parameter to the form instantation, not to the save method; there shouldn't be any reason to pass it explicitly to save.

Comment: You could make it default: e.g. `instance=None`. Then, inside the func you could do some conditional like `if instance is not None:`. But I'm afraid that `save` is called "internally" by _Django_ and it doesn't pass the argument.

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L431), you'll see that `save` only takes `commit` as a `kwarg`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's what it was, I was passing instance in the `save()` method when I should have placed it in the instantation. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

In django documentation it is clearly stated that save() only takes commit as argument.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    updatedOrder = super(UpdatedOrderForm, self).save(commit=False)

    # do other things related to form
    if commit:
        updatedOrder.save()
    return updatedOrder
```

Earlier we saved it in updatedOrder but did not committed to do some operations related to form and once everything is done then commit to database.